# firewalld updating ipset entry timeout

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, firewalld, netfilter

I have been trying to figure out how to update the timeout of an ipset entry, with no luck so far, when using native ipset I would just simply use:

```
$ ipset add foo 192.168.0.5 timout N -exist
```

but firewalld doesn't seems to implement this feature according to the manual (man), which is a pretty useful and common.
ip2ban seems to bypass firewalld ipset implmentation and just use it natively, so have I tried but with no success:

ipset creation:

```
$ ipset create foo hash:ip timeout 300
```

direct rule:

```
$ firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p TCP -m multiport --dports 22,443 -m set --match-set foo src -j ACCEPT
```

```
$ ipset add foo 192.120.11.1
```

https requests and ssh connection attemp are dropped with no route to host.
as soon as I disable firewalld i can succeffule send request and connecto to ssh.

- I'm using the default zone:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s3
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules:
ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p TCP -m multiport --dports 22,443 -m set --match-set foo src -j ACCEPT

what I'm doing wrong, is this possible with firewalld?

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume the ip is actually being added to the ipset when you add it manually? You checked the output of `ipset list foo`?